# How to sort dataframe in descending order

Tags: r, sorting

I have a `data.frame(v1,v2,y)`

```
v1: 1 5 8 6 1 1 6 8

v2: 2 6 9 8 4 5 2 3

y: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
```

and now I want it sorted by y like this:

```
y: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4

v1: 1 8 1 6 5 6 1 8

v2: 2 9 4 2 6 8 5 3
```

I tried:

```
sorted <- df[,,sort(df$y)]
```

but this does not work.. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ave` from `base R` to create a sequence by 'y' group and `order` on it

```
df[order(with(df, ave(y, y, FUN = seq_along))),]
#  v1 v2 y
#1  1  2 1
#3  8  9 2
#5  1  4 3
#7  6  2 4
#2  5  6 1
#4  6  8 2
#6  1  5 3
#8  8  3 4
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1, 5, 8, 6, 1, 1, 6, 8), 
                  v2 = c(2, 6, 9, 8, 4, 5, 2, 3), 
                  y = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try a tidyverse solution

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(y, v1, v2) %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(n=1:n()) %>% 
  arrange(n, y) %>% 
  select(-n) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 8 x 3
      y    v1    v2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     2
2     2     8     9
3     3     1     4
4     4     6     2
5     1     5     6
6     2     6     8
7     3     1     5
8     4     8     3
```

data:

```
v1 <- c(1, 5, 8, 6, 1, 1, 6, 8)
v2<- c( 2, 6, 9, 8, 4, 5, 2, 3)
y<- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4 )
```

Idea is to add an index along y and then arrange by the index and y.

Comment: you could also use `mutate(n = row_number())`

Answer (score 1):

You could also do alternating subset twice and `rbind` these together:

```
rbind(df[c(TRUE,FALSE),], df[c(FALSE,TRUE),])
```

The result:

```
  v1 v2 y
1  1  2 1
3  8  9 2
5  1  4 3
7  6  2 4
2  5  6 1
4  6  8 2
6  1  5 3
8  8  3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `matrix()` to reorder the indizes of the rows:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1, 5, 8, 6, 1, 1, 6, 8), 
                 v2 = c(2, 6, 9, 8, 4, 5, 2, 3), 
                 y = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4))
df[c(matrix(1:nrow(df), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)),]
#   v1 v2 y
# 1  1  2 1
# 3  8  9 2
# 5  1  4 3
# 7  6  2 4
# 2  5  6 1
# 4  6  8 2
# 6  1  5 3
# 8  8  3 4
```

The solution uses the property in which order the elements of the matrix are stored (in R it is like in FORTRAN) - the index of the first dimension  is running first. In FORTRAN one uses the terminus *leading dimension* for the number of values for this first dimension (for a 2-dimensional array, i.e. a matrix, it is the number of rows).

Comment: @Renu No, that will reproduce the original dataframe - not the desired output.